# How does the AutoHide of the taskbar work (programatically)

Tags: .net, winapi, animation, windows-7, taskbar

I am thinking a writing an app to talk to my Windows taskbar.  I want to know what processes are causing it to not auto-hide.

Any one know a good place to start to get this kind of info?  Documentation?

Info on how to have my app notify the taskbar to stay up would work too (I could at least get started there).

Basically, I am sick and tired of my taskbar not auto-hiding and not having any notifications or anything point to any process that is causing it to not auto-hide.  I would like to write a tool to find and KILL the process that is holding it up.

I would prefer to .NET and C# if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are few articles on www.codeproject.com

for example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Taskbar_Manipulation.aspx

there are few more for Windows Vista and Windows 7